# Adding silence between words in audio file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpy

What I am trying to do is to `concat` `wav` files which contain short audios.
I am able to `concat` them into one file, but I am trying to set each file at a specific time.

Currently, I can `concat` the files but I can't place each one at the specific time they need to be. I thought maybe I can just add the right amount of silence between them and solve the problem this way. I am new to `ffmpeg`

I have a text file with the file names i.e. `text.txt`

```
file a.wav
file b.wav
file c.wav
```

and I use this cmd:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i text.txt out.mp3
```

This works, but is there a way to add a specified number of minutes of silence between them?

I tried to put this in the text file, but it didn't work:

```
file a.wav
inpoint 5
outpoint 10
file b.wav
inpoint 10
outpoint 20
file c.wav
inpoint 20
outpoint 25
```

Comment: make a few 'silent' wav clips of varying length and build a function to add them to your series as required

Comment: @RobertRowntree method is sound :/ but you don't need multiple silent WAVs. Just one will do - as long as its length is equal to the maximum silence that you need. Insert it in the concat text file as necessary. and set `outpoint` for silence. Note that `inpoint` and `outpoint` specify position within that input, not the output file.

Comment: @Gyan thanks for your comments, great solution. I appreciate it.

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thanks for your solution as well. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **aevalsrc** filter to generate silence audio. Then use the **concat** filter to merge them all.

Here is a simple example:

```
E:\video\tmp>ffmpeg -i a.wav -i b.wav -filter_complex "aevalsrc=exprs=0:d=5[silence], [0:a] [silence] [1:a] concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map "[outa]" out.mp3
```

For `aevalsrc` filter, `aevalsrc=exprs=0:d=5[silence]`. `exprs` specifies the output value. `d` means the duration in seconds. `[silence]` is your output label. This filter also supports specifying the sample rate, number of samples and so on.

Check this page for detail:

http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

Comment: just an observation... I needed to put 's' just after the number to specify it as seconds.